# Symfony 5: Wire manually Controller method arguments

Tags: symfony, testing, controller, symfony5

I am trying to mock a service in order to test one of my controller's method:

```
class ExampleController extends AbstractController
{
     /**
     * @Route("/example", name="app_example", methods={"POST"})
     */
     public function exampleMethod(Request $request, IService $service) {}
}
```

In test environment, I would like to wire a mock of the service, but I cannot find out how manually wire controller arguments (as opposed to service arguments). This is what I did so far, but it's not working:

```
//services_test.yaml

  App\Controller\ExampleController:
    arguments:
      $service: '@App\Service\ServiceMock'
```

I get the following error:

```
Invalid service "App\Controller\ExampleController": class has no constructor.
```

Comment: `arguments` directive provide a way to inject dependency through constructor, so if you use it you have to add constructor as said @user9245255. Could you add codes of unit test case please.

Comment: Are you trying to do some sort of integration test?  If so then you would just define your service in the test environment.  The Symfony code that actually injects arguments into action methods is not something that you can modify.  At least not easily.

Answer (score -2):

Try to add a constructor in your controller and make the IService as its parameter

Comment: How exactly would adding it to the constructor allow injecting a different implementation in the test environment?